# How to Create a Dataprep recipe?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, iot, google-cloud-dataprep, google-cloud-iot

I am learning how to work with Cloud Dataprep by Trifacta on qwiklabs [Streaming IoT Data to Dataprep](https://googlecoursera.qwiklabs.com/focuses/23171). The instruction to follow is quite clear and I have not encountered any problems yet, but when I try to Create a Dataprep recipe (Split column **On delimiter**) with *temp-sensor* as the delimiter, I get this error:

> Error
>   Invalid parameter. Please ensure that the syntax is correct

This renders the Add option unavailable, and I can't proceed. What am I doing wrong and how can I proceed?
The picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I realised that this is nothing complex. **The delimiter should be in quotes( 'delimiter' or "delimiter" also would work).**

*In my case it is **"temp-sensor-"**.*

I guess learning anything at first seems complex until you actually do it.